# How to add a css transition color change for a link/div background

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-transitions

I want the whole div to change from `#555555` to `#b13c19`. It's a simple rounded corner div wrapped around a link. I cant seem to get it right. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

***HTML***

```
<div id="resume_btn">
   <a href="Aalok_Resume.pdf"> Click Here to View My Resume </a>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
#resume_btn {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #555555;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -0-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}

#resume_btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'oswald', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

I'm not sure where to put the `-moz-transition: background 1s ease-in;` etc. properties. I want the background to change color when I hover over the link. I made it work for the background color of the link but it doesn't look good because the background only encompasses the wording and not the whole 230 x 25 area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#resume_btn {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #555555;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -ms-border-radius: 10px;
         -0-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px; 

    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
       -moz-transition: background 1s;
        -ms-transition: background 1s;
         -o-transition: background 1s;
            transition: background 1s;
}

#resume_btn:hover {
    background:  #b13c19;
}

#resume_btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font: 300 18px 'oswald', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="resume_btn">
  <a href="Aalok_Resume.pdf"> Click Here to View My Resume </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "didn't work?" it works perfectly, just take a look at the JSFiddle

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I tried that also...don't know why it didn't work last time. I know it wont work for IE but i could care less. My target audience isn't dumb enough to still be using IE anyway. I know that's bad coding ethics but this is my personal site.

Comment: It should work in IE. Also, you don't necessarily need that wrapper div to style the link that way. - http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/LTsag/60/